# Sugestion about clean code with builder java

Tags: java

I've got two similar parts of code and they only invoke different method of builder:

```
return search.stream().map(s -> {
            List<PartDto> results = retrieveSimilarParts(extendedSimilarParts, s.getVdi4081());

            return CollectionUtils.isNullOrEmpty(results) ? null : PartResultDto.builder()
                    .identifier(s.getIdentifier())
                    .extendedSimilarParts(results).build();
        }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
return search.stream().map(s -> {
                List<PartDto> results = retrieveSimilarParts(similarParts, s.getVdi4081());

                return CollectionUtils.isNullOrEmpty(results) ? null : PartResultDto.builder()
                        .identifier(s.getIdentifier())
                        .similarParts(results).build();
            }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The only difference is invoking:
extendedSimilarParts
similarParts
How could I extract clean method?

Comment: just pass it as a lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you have a builder that keeps using the same parameters, you should consider creating a constructor there. This will allow you to do something like this:

```
results = new PartResultDto(s.getIdentifier(), results)
```

Then, I would avoid code blocks inside the stream pipeline, so, in your example, I would break the map into 2 different map methods: firstly to call `retrieveSimilarParts`, and, after that, to create the dto (this will allow you to move the filter between the two, resulting a a much more clear code - imo):

```
search.stream()
    .map(s -> retrieveSimilarParts(similarParts, s.getVdi4081())
    .filter(results -> !CollectionUtils.isNullOrEmpty(results))
    .map(results -> new PartResultDto(s.getIdentifier(), results))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Lastly, you can replace the filter with a method reference, the not predicate for the filter, and perhaps the `.toList` instead of the collector

```
search.stream()
    .map(s -> retrieveSimilarParts(similarParts, s.getVdi4081())
    .filter(not(CollectionUtils::isNullOrEmpty))
    .map(results -> new PartResultDto(s.getIdentifier(), results))
    .toList();:
```